# How to get Dependabot to create PRs for Cargo.toml, not Cargo.lock?

Tags: dependency-management

I want to receive automatic dependency update GitHub notifications for a Rust binary package. I have a Cargo.toml like this:

```
[package]
...
[dependencies]
sophia = "0.8.0-alpha.1"
actix-web = "4"
multimap = "0.9"
tinytemplate = "1"
log = "0.4"
```

However when I create `.github/dependabot.yml` like this, I receive tons of pull requests that do not change anything in `Cargo.toml`, only `Cargo.lock`:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "cargo"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

However I can't ignore minor versions like the following, because that would not give me updates for `0.x.y` dependencies when x increases:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "cargo"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    allow:
      - dependency-type: "direct"
    ignore:
      - update-types: ["version-update:semver-minor", "version-update:semver-patch"]
```

How can I get Dependabot to only open PRs when Cargo.toml is changed not only Cargo.lock? There is a `versioning-strategy` of `lockfile-only` but that is exactly the opposite of what I need.